# jQuery Fullpage - Show current section position with horizontal line on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I am trying to show line as an indicator for active section in fullpage.js based page.

This page has several section & subsection and active section should show as a horizontal red line upto active nav.

for example  if i am on section one then line should be of teh width of first section and if i am on section section the line width should be upto end of section section and so.

Link for [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JRJOkb)
 [image]

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section" data-anchor="one">Section One</div>
  <div class="section" data-anchor="two">Section Two</div>
  <div class="section">Section Two sub page one</div>
  <div class="section">Section Two sub page two</div>
  <div class="section" data-anchor="three">Section Three</div>
  <div class="section" data-anchor="four">Section Four</div>
</div>

<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <hr>
  <ul id="myMenu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="active"><a href="#one">First section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#two">Second section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="thirdPage"><a href="#three">Third section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="fourthPage"><a href="#four">Fourth section</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>



.section {
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 3em;
}
.content{
  margin:50px
}
#myMenu{position:absolute; background-color:#eee; top:0; width:100%; margin:0px !important; padding:0px !important;}

.active{font-size:15px; background-color:purple; }
.nav-wrapper{position:absolute; height:20px; bottom:0;width:100%; z-index:999999999; background:blue;}
.nav-wrapper > ul li {list-style:none; display:inline-block; padding:0px !important; margin:0px ; margin-left:-4px; text-align:center;}
.nav-wrapper ul li{width:calc(100% / 4);}
hr {
  background: #f00  none repeat scroll 0 0;
  height: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999999999;
  margin:-5px
}
```

how can i do this using jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since some of your pages are subpages that don't exists in your menu you will have to extract the pages and save them in a different variable:

```
var visibleMenuSections = $('#myMenu a').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
}).get()
```

Now this variable contains an Array of the links:

```
["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

Once you have this array you can use the callback `afterLoad` of the `fullpage` to set the with of the `hr` after each page change:

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
    p = visibleMenuSections.indexOf(anchorLink);
    if (p > -1) {
        $('.nav-wrapper hr').width((p+1) * (100/visibleMenuSections.length) + '%');
    }
}
```

Here is a working jsfiddle:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGOYmA

> Note - you had a problem in your html - the values of the `data-menuanchor` in the menu should be the exact values of the `data-anchor` of the section.

Here is an updated version of the jsfiddle (with a bit of css changes):
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGXZaG

Comment: Excellent solution